# Knife throws failed to allocate memory error

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I'm getting '[FATAL] failed to allocate memory' error while trying to get the status of all nodes in Chef organization using knife

```
<UserName>@<Hostname> /C/chef/knife_WS
$ knife status > nodes-status.csv
[FATAL] failed to allocate memory
```

How to fix this memory related error?

Comment: How many nodes do you have?

Answer (score 0):

This most likely means you either have too many nodes or not enough RAM. `knife status` was written long ago and so was never updated to use some of the newer APIs that save on memory, so it tries to load the full node data for every node in your system into RAM at once (twice actually, because it then makes a sorted copy of the array).